# How to get parent widget on which contextMenu() was called

Tags: python, pyqt5

I Have a treeWidget on which I am calling customContextMenu . 
but i am not able to get the widgetItem on which it was called.

I tried reading documentation but found nothing

the treewidget:

```
self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(self.centralwidget)
self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, "Database Explorer")
self.treeWidget.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
self.treeWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.openMenu)

def openMenu(self,position):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        deleteAction = menu.addAction("Delete")
        showAction = menu.addAction("Show")
        action = menu.exec_(self.treeWidget.mapToGlobal(position))
        if action == deleteAction:
            self.my_function(treeWidgetItemObject)
```

I want to get object of treeWidgetItem on which contextMenu was called in my_function()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `indexAt()` if you want to get the QModelIndex associated with the item pressed or `itemAt()` returned by the QTreeWidgetItem

```
def openMenu(self,position):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        deleteAction = menu.addAction("Delete")
        showAction = menu.addAction("Show")
        pos = self.treeWidget.viewport().mapToGlobal(position)
        action = menu.exec_(pos)
        if action == deleteAction:
            ix = self.treeWidget.indexAt(position)
            if ix.isValid():
                print(ix.data())
                it = self.treeWidget.itemFromIndex(ix)
                texts = [it.text(c) for c in range(it.columnCount())]
                print(texts)
```